# Hololens- Failed to Connect to Device

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I realize this question was asked elsewhere, but the answers seem to direct towards the paring process between Hololens and a PC, which is part of my problem.

I made an app in Unity and exported to Visual Studio. When I try to run it on the Hololens, I get this error:

> Error DEP6957 : Failed to connect to device using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings.

I understand that the first time you run, you should be prompted to pair both the PC and the device, but I never got this request, and I have no field to input the Hololens PIN that is found on the Settings app. I tried both with the USB cable and by WIFI, following instructions from: https://developer.microsoft.com/EN-US/WINDOWS/HOLOGRAPHIC/holograms_100, but with no success.

Is there anything that I can do to debug, and succeed in trying my app on the Hololens?

P.S. I am running visual studio on Windows 8, and I can't download the emulator because it seems that I'm lacking Hyper-V. Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building for Hololens requires UWP. To build UWP app for Unity these requirements must be met:

- Unity 5.2 or later
- A Windows 10 machine
- Visual Studio 2015 RTM, (the minimum version is 14.0.23107.0). Please
  note that earlier versions, for example Visual Studio RC, are not
  supported in Unity 5.2.
- You’ll also need to install the Windows 10 SDK.

Like you mentioned, you are using *Windows 8* but *Windows 10* is required. 
You can read more bout this on Unity [blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/09/09/windows-10-universal-apps-in-unity-5-2/).

Comment: Thank you! If you feel this question might be relevant to other programmers in the future I would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: I think it would be.

Comment: You say you are lacking Hyper-V but you can enable it. You need Windows 10 for that too. Its good to have the emulator. It saves time sometimes.

Comment: I had done it. Must have been a problem with my conection! Sorry for the delay

Comment: Can I develop Hololens without enabling Hyper-V? My MacBook Pro 2016 has been un-bootable to Windows when I turned on Hyper-V supporting. I have a real Hololens and I want to build directly, not using emulator. Can I achieve it? I heard that when installing Visual Studio, it will turn on Hyper-V automatically.

Comment: @nynohu I think you can.Hyper-V is usually used for emulators. By the way, I use Hyper-V on my MBP 2015 without problems. You are likely doing something wrong.  If you are going to use Windows on a Mac make sure to use bootcamp install of other emulator software. Also make sure to install drivers from apple bootcamp.

Comment: @Programmer I exactly installed windows 10 pro using bootcamp. After I enabled Hyper-V in Windows features, it required restart. After restarting, the computer was showing loading screen and could not boot to windows anymore. I must recovery my MBP for fixing this issue. And the MBP from 2013 did not support Hyper-V as I found out: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7771861?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Don't know what's wrong but yes, you can develop with Hololens without Hyper-V.

Comment: I don't like to use the emulator so I don't use hyper-V, yet develop for hololens

Comment: by the way, nobody answered how to pair the hololens again (which I think was part of the question?)

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation recently. I don’t have the pro windows 10 version therefore no Hyper-V. However i was able to establish the connection Using the Hololens App from the Windows store, after connecting i created a new user and then i was able to pair using Wifi and USB

Answer (score -2):

If after the update to windows 10 the problem still happens, here is a simple way to solve it.

First I was running applications in the Hololens already when suddenly I got the error message described in the original question.

So, I went to the Project Properties. The Debug Tab. There there is the "Remote Machine" space. My Hololens was selected there. But I pressed the [Find] Button and in the window that appeared I selected my hololens (it was on). Alternatively you could put the Hololens IP address there. Put Ok and voila! it works as before

Comment: *"Although there is an accepted answer, in my opinion it does not answer the question."*. The accepted answer said *"you are using Windows 8 but Windows 10 is required."* Clearly, the requirement is not met but to you, the question is not answered.