# Hololens Emulator Networkproblems

Tags: hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have the Problem that, when I run the app (made with Unity) the emulator says over speakers: "**next you neet to sign in with your account you use on this device.**" This commando comes more often over the speakers...

VS ('15 with Update 3) brings up the ErrorMessage:"The Windows Store-App "nameoftheapp_pzq3xp76mxafg!App" cant be activated. The activation request failed with "Access denied"

I read that the vEthernet(Internal Ethernet Port Microsoft Emulator NAT Switch) must be activated. After the installation it was. But than I have no internet access with VS and Internet Explorer?!?

Further informations I found here: [Hololens- Failed to Connect to Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787587/hololens-failed-to-connect-to-device)

But in the Hyper-V Manager I can't even find the Emulator...

Could it not work because:

- I m not working as administrator and have always to type in the local admin password?
- Limited network settings (Firewall,rights) because I'm at the workplace
- Didnt look in the BIOS settings like [install the tools](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install_the_tools) says?

By the way, on the drives (over USB) it works perfect.

Maybe that helps to my explanation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyKQb.png)

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution? Thanks